# Quantizing an array so that a subset of quantized values is still consistently quantized

Tags: ruby, rounding, quantization

Given an array of `int`s I want to quantize each value so that the sum of quantized values is 100. Each quantized value should also be an integer. This works when the whole array is quantized, but when a subset of quantized values is added up it doesn't remain quantized with respect to the rest of the values.

For example, the values 44, 40, 7, 2, 0, 0 are quantized to 47, 43, 8, 2, 0, 0 (the sum of which is 100). If you take the last 4 quantized values the sum is 53 which is consistent with the first value (i.e. 47 + 53 = 100).

But with the values 78, 7, 7, 1, 0, 0, the sum of the last 4 quantized values (8, 8, 1, 0, 0) is 17. The first quantized value is 84 which when added to 17 does not equal 100. Clearly the reason for this is due to the rounding. Is there a way to adjust the rounding so that subsets are still consistent?

Here is the Ruby code:

```
class Quantize
  def initialize(array)
    @array = array.map { |a| a.to_i }
  end

  def values
    @array.map { |a| quantize(a) }
  end

  def sub_total(i, j)
    @array[i..j].map { |a| quantize(a) }.reduce(:+)
  end

  private

  def quantize(val)
    (val * 100.0 / total).round(0)
  end

  def total
    @array.reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

And the (failing) tests:

```
require 'quantize'

describe Quantize do
  context 'first example' do
    let(:subject) { described_class.new([44, 40, 7, 2, 0, 0]) }

    context '#values' do
      it 'quantizes array to add up to 100' do
        expect(subject.values).to eq([47, 43, 8, 2, 0, 0])
      end
    end

    context '#sub_total' do
      it 'adds a subset of array' do
        expect(subject.sub_total(1, 5)).to eq(53)
      end
    end
  end

  context 'second example' do
    let(:subject) { described_class.new([78, 7, 7, 1, 0, 0]) }

    context '#values' do
      it 'quantizes array to add up to 100' do
        expect(subject.values).to eq([84, 8, 8, 1, 0, 0])
      end
    end

    context '#sub_total' do
      it 'adds a subset of array' do
        expect(subject.sub_total(1, 5)).to eq(16)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Running your code, the quantization of your second example — as you say in your test cases — is [84, 8, 8, 1, 0, 0]. This adds to 101 — not to 100, as you desire. Moreover, the sum of the last 5 digits is 17 — not 15, as you state in your question. So there is a deeper problem than that which you describe in your question. That is, the rounding is flawed, period. It's not really about the subsets.

Comment: @M.AnthonyAiello you're right. The discrepancy was due to a poor edit. I will fix it.

Comment: @ReedGLaw - The edit helps — but the issue is still more fundamental than the subsets. The second example doesn't add up to 100 — it adds up to 101. So 1) your algorithm doesn't do what you want in the first place, never mind about subsets; and 2) your test case doesn't expose the error. For the latter, I would suggest summing the quantized values to ensure that they equal 100, rather than specifying what the quantization must be.

Comment: @M.AnthonyAiello once again you're right. Looking at the unrounded results of the second example, (83.87097, 7.52688, 7.52688, 1.07527, 0.0, 0.0), I see it's not evident what the test should expect. Should one of the 7.52688 values be rounded up to 8 and the other down to 7? I should describe the actual problem in more detail. The original values represent patients in clinical trials. The six elements of the array each represent an adverse event grade (from 0 being no adverse event to 5 being death). These values should be presented in a table as percentages so that they appear consistent.

Comment: (Continued from last comment) ... So in the second example, 78 patients were grade 0 (no adverse event), 7 were grade 1, 7 were grade 2, and 1 was grade 3. There were a total of 93 (78+7+7+1) patients. For the final table, percentages are displayed rather than the number of patients. The percentages should appear consistent so that they add up to 100.

Comment: @ReedGLaw Hmm. I think we're outside the realm of asking about programming. I suggest that attempting to represent the results in terms of integer percents is fundamentally flawed: it will inject bias into your results no matter how you do the rounding. Perhaps there is a different *Exchange where you could ask that question? (Also, your problem really isn't "quantization" — that's about taking something continuous and representing it with discrete values. You're really trying to scale your results, as if you had 100 trials.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74383/discussion-between-m-anthony-aiello-and-reed-g-law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments on the question, the quantization routine does not perform correctly: the second example `[78, 7, 7, 1, 0, 0]` is quantized as `[84, 8, 8, 1, 0, 0]` — which adds to 101 and not to 100.

Here is an approach that will yield correct results:

```
def quantize(array, value)
  quantized = array.map(&:to_i)
  total = array.reduce(:+)
  remainder = value - total

  index = 0

  if remainder > 0
    while remainder > 0 
      quantized[index] += 1
      remainder -= 1
      index = (index + 1) % quantized.length
    end
  else
    while remainder < 0 
      quantized[index] -= 1
      remainder += 1
      index = (index + 1) % quantized.length
    end
  end

  quantized
end
```

This solves your problem, as stated in the question. The troublesome result becomes `[80, 8, 8, 2, 1, 1]`, which adds to 100 and maintains the subset relationship that you described. The solution can, of course, be made more performant — but it has the advantage of working and being dead simple to understand.

Comment: Reading the code it seems this cycles through the array adding or subtracting 1 from each value until the total equals `value`. The trouble with this solution is, if you've read my description of the problem domain in the question's comments, you'll see that it appears that 1% of patients have died (`quantized[4]`), when in reality none (`array[4]`) have died. Also, `quantized[0]` is 80 but that's pretty far from the actual percentage value of 83.87097. If some values must be fudged, I'd rather it be the 7.52688's (`quantized[1..2]`). That would mean one rounds up to 8 and the other down to 7.

Comment: Indeed. But the original parameters of the question did not stipulate those restrictions. I wasn't even aware that you required scaling, until your later comment. This does solve the problem, as originally stated.

Comment: I think this could be adjusted though to make it work. All I'd have to do is skip array elements that equal 0. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I should have used the term "scaling" all along. My mistake for not knowing what to call this problem. Quantization is used for a continuous set of values (like a signal) being constrained to a relatively small discrete set. I just want to represent a set of numbers on a different scale.